Projectivity of generic fibres, the definition of elliptic fibration
The definition I have for elliptic fibration is

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and an elliptic fibration is a surjection $f:X\to C$ where $C$ is a smooth projective curve and the generic fibre of $f$ is a smooth curve of genus $1$.

However, as the name suggests, this generic fibre should be an elliptic curve (perhaps without an origin), so does that mean projectivity of the generic fibre is automatic? I think I am missing a silly point and I cannot prove it.
Thanks for your help!

X and C are projective therefore the morphism is automatically proper, hence so are the fibers. Proper schemes of dimension one are projective.

@CraniumClamp Thank you!  Is there a reference on the fibers of proper morphisms being proper?

@Ja_1941 What do you know about the fiber of a map of schemes?

@Daniel Since properness is preserved by fibre product, the generic fibre is proper over the residue field of the generic fibre. Does that imply properness over the base field? I think I probably just forget some easy fact there.

@Ja_1941 not sure why you are attempting to view the generic fiber over the base field. The generic fiber is a projective genus 1 curve over k(C), the function field of C
